# Does calling removeFromSuperview() on lazy created view instantiate it?

Tags: swift

In one of my view controllers, I have a lot of possible subviews that can be created based on the status of the data received. I am trying to make them class variables so they can be accessible throughout the file and am using lazy so that I don't create views I don't need. However, I need to make sure the views that could be displayed get removed if the status changes and would want to call .removeFromSuperview(). But I know that lazy variables get initialized the first time they get referenced and that would defeat the purpose of trying to save memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you referenced the lazy variable in order to call `removeFromSuperview`, it would first create the view and then call `removeFromSuperview` on it. You should likely design another way, without `lazy`. I would recommend starting with the simplest approach (such as Optional properties, checking if it's nil, and creating it if necessary), and then extracting duplicated code. `lazy` solves one very specific problem in a very limited way. If you don't need precisely what it offers, you generally will need to build something custom

Comment: So in order to free up memory and remove the view, would I call .removeFromSuperview() first and then make the variable = nil?

Comment: Correct. Using optional chaining (`theView?.removeFromSuperview(); theView = nil`), it would be fine whether or not the property were currently `nil`. You may consider putting the `removeFromSuperview` code in the `didSet` handler for the property (and if you do this quite a lot, you can look at property wrappers to automate that). I'm not suggesting you make this more complex than is valuable, however. Only add layers if they're really helpful.